# List users in login screen in ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: server, login

Is it possible to see which users currently exist in  ubuntu server 12.04 in login prompt without authentication? In command prompt, is such thing possible?

Comment: This looks possible using `/etc/issue` or `/etc/issue.d/01-your-file` files, perhaps by directing the output of `w` to the issue file. This question relates: https://askubuntu.com/q/1455906/29073 somewhat and might give someone a start.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this without actually logging in. The method to do that is with the package [`pam_motd`](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/pam_motd.html) (it will already be installed on your system).

> When logging into an Ubuntu server you may have noticed the informative Message Of The Day (MOTD). This information is obtained and displayed using a couple of packages:

`pam_motd` executes the scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d` in order based on the number prepended to the script. The output of the scripts is written to `/var/run/motd`, keeping the numerical order, then concatenated with `/etc/motd.tail`.

Create `/usr/local/bin/whoisloggedin`, a simple shell script to show `who`:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#
# Prints who is logged in for the MOTD.
#
#
echo
who
echo
```

Make the script executable:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/whoisloggedin
```

Next, create a symlink to `/etc/update-motd.d/98-whoisloggedin`:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/whoisloggedin /etc/update-motd.d/98-whoisloggedin
```

Finally, exit the server and re-login to view the new MOTD.