# How can I have Ubuntu display the output of a commad in the login screen on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: command-line, server, login, text

*I've found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252057/how-can-i-display-a-message-on-the-login-screen), but it talks about a version of Ubuntu with a GUI. I'm referring to Ubuntu Server, so no GUI. I've also found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1429170/display-python-output-on-login-screen), but it doesn't look like it will display the output of a command, but instead only static text.*

The Ubuntu Server login screen looks something like this:

```
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS mycomputer tty1
mycomputer login:
```

However, I'd like it to run a command (either as `root` or under my account - you can pick), and then I'd like it to print the output of the command before giving the login prompt.

For example, if my command was `echo Hello world!`, I'd like it to look like this:

```
Hello world!
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS mycomputer tty1
mycomputer login:
```

Or this would be fine too:

```
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS mycomputer tty1
Hello world!
mycomputer login:
```

While it was in my example, the output of my command can change - it isn't gaurenteed to be the same each time, so I can't hardcode the output of the command into a file (in my case, the command is `hostname -i`, which prints the IP address).

I often need to check the IP of a machine, and it would be easier if I didn't have to sign in to check it. For the sake of the question, assume this is a personal server on a home network, and so leaking the IP address isn't a concern.

How can I display the output of a command in the command-line login screen?

Comment: I think there is a mistake in thinking on your end - the login prompt is there once your machine booted, it is just waiting to be connected to. Thus, what you intend to do equals to running a script at boot time -> use a systemd Service Unit. You can run a script after logging in with a systemd User Unit. However, they are both executed in the background, thus any output goes into the logs of journald as a standard.

Comment: Related: [How to run a bash script while Ubuntu is starting up on tty](https://askubuntu.com/q/1319352)

Answer (score 9):

As you already discovered, the appearance of the server login screen is controlled by a *getty* program - by default, that's `agetty` on Ubuntu. The `agetty` program reads from a file named `/etc/issue` - and since agetty version 2.35, optionally from files in `/etc/issue.d`. From `man agetty`:

> ### ISSUE FILES
>
> ```
>    The default issue file is /etc/issue. If the file exists, then agetty
>    also checks for /etc/issue.d directory. The directory is optional
>    extension to the default issue file and content of the directory is
>    printed after /etc/issue content. If the /etc/issue does not exist,
>    then the directory is ignored. All files with .issue extension from the
>    directory are printed in version-sort order. The directory can be used
>    to maintain 3rd-party messages independently on the primary system
>    /etc/issue file.
> ```

So the procedure is:

1. create the `/etc/issue.d/` directory if it does not already exist
2. create a script to run your command and write its output to a `.issue` file in that directory
3. modify the template `getty@.service` to execute the script via its `ExecStartPre`

Proof of concept (tested on a 22.04 desktop VM):

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/issue.d

sudo nano /usr/local/sbin/issue
```

with content

```
    #!/bin/sh

    /bin/date +'Hello world @ %c' > /etc/issue.d/50hello.issue
```

(the `date` command so we can confirm the content is generated dynamically).

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/issue
```

Now make a local copy of the agetty@ service file:

```
sudo cp --no-clobber /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service /etc/systemd/system
```

Edit the copy with your favorite text editor and add the `ExecStartPre` instruction:

```
[Service]
# the VT is cleared by TTYVTDisallocate
# The '-o' option value tells agetty to replace 'login' arguments with an
# option to preserve environment (-p), followed by '--' for safety, and then
# the entered username.

ExecStartPre=-/usr/local/sbin/issue
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' --noclear %I $TERM
.
.
etc.
```

The leading "-" stops the whole unit from failing if your ExecStartPre command fails from some reason.

It should work right away if you switch to a *new* TTY - to see the effect in an existing TTY you may need to restart the instance service ex. `sudo systemctl restart getty@tty2.service`

[image: tty2]

Comment: I wonder if you even need the issue file. Just running the command whose output is to be shown in `ExecStartPre` should work, right? It should show the output in the TTY? Or does it go to the journal? Or does getty clear the output?

Comment: @muru that's a good thought - I'll give it a try

Comment: FWIW I tried (Kubuntu 22.10) putting `$(host -I)` (the switch is capital-i) in /etc/issue but it was echoed (printed without processing) instead of being executed. Per my answer, `\4` worked for all TTY I'd not visited since boot.

Comment: Note files in `issue.d/` need to have an extension like `05-your-filename.issue`, they don't get used otherwise!

Answer (score 2):

After login `motd` (not exactly what is needed):

```
# cat /etc/update-motd.d/00-update
```

```
#!/bin/bash
echo
echo "Server IP: $(hostname -i)"
```

Don't forget

```
chmod +x /etc/update-motd.d/00-update
```

Doc:

```
man update-motd
```

Comment: I've never used it, but aren't `motd` shown after login, eg as stated here, https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/motd.5.html . OP wants to modify the login prompt itself. Maybe the systemd motd can show before login?? I skimmed and didn't see anything in the man page you linked.

Comment: If he want to change the motd, just `printf '\n%s\n' "Server IP: $(hostname -i)" > /etc/motd`

Comment: As mentioned - motd displays **after** login. This is not the correct answer.

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Answer (score 1):

**Pre-login** the banner is provided by **`/etc/issue`**.

This file by default for me on Kubuntu 22.10 contains a single line:

```
Ubuntu 22.10 \n \l
```

The \char look like escape codes but they're not what you expect, the `man issue` output has your back here:

```
The issue files may contain certain escape codes to display the system name, date, time et cetera. All escape codes consist of a backslash (\)
       immediately followed by one of the characters listed below.

       **4 or 4{interface}**
           Insert the IPv4 address of the specified network interface (for example: \4{eth0}). If the interface argument is not specified, then select
           the first fully configured (UP, non-LOCALBACK, RUNNING) interface. If no configured interface is found, fall back to the IP address of the
           machine’s hostname.

       **6 or 6{interface}**
           The same as \4 but for IPv6.
```

So, adding "\4" (without quotes) to `/etc/issue` will print the IP address. Neat. Note that it only works on TTY that you haven't yet entered [since the last reboot?]; you can logout of a TTY and it resets the issue banner. Also `\n` is not a carriage return, whitespace is preserved, but instead is the "nodename" which for me is the same as the output from `host`.

This is only for TTY's, if you want a banner for remote login then you'll need to look at the program that provides the remote shell, such as SSH (see `sshd_config` file).

===

Edit:
I also had a file called `issue.net`, but that seems to be vestigial (old and unworking). `/etc/issue` is from the base-files package. I did not have an `/etc/issue.d` directory but making one, adding a file with extension ".issue" works. I didn't test extensively; `apt-file search "/issue.d"` returns only the package `freedombox` (which I've never heard of).

Comment: Ah, just saw @steeldriver's answer after I researched this. I think I cover some different details so I'll leave it in place.